# How to detect subnet IP?

Tags: php

I have this code for detect ipv4:

```
public static function isSubnet($ip = NULL)
{
    $remoteAddr = (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) && isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) ? $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] : NULL);
    $ip = strToLower(is_null($ip) ? $remoteAddr : $ip);

    $part = explode('.', $ip);
    // 10.0.0.0/8   Private network
    // 127.0.0.0/8  Loopback
    // 169.254.0.0/16 & ::1  Link-Local
    // 172.16.0.0/12  Private network
    // 192.168.0.0/16  Private network
    if (count($part) === 4 && ($part[0] === '10' || $part[0] === '127' || ($part[0] === '172' && $part[1] < 16 && $part[1] > 31)
        || ($part[0] === '169' && $part[1] === '254') || ($part[0] === '192' && $part[1] === '168'))
    ) {

        return TRUE;

    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

1. Is it right way to detect ipv4 subnet or you have better idea for that? If yes please give me a example (code).
2. How to detect subnet of ipv6 if it is possible?

Comment: Sounds like something you should ask on SuperUser.

Comment: @AmalMurali, What for?  This relates to programming, as much as any program relates to what it does.

Comment: What do you mean by "detect ipv4 subnet"? A subnet is part of a network, not an IP. An IP may be a member of multiple networks of different sizes.

Comment: dev-null-dweller: Give me a right answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP has bulit-in mechanism to validate some common types, for your case it would be:

```
$isIP = filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP);

$isSubnet = !filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, 
    FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE | FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE
);

return $isIP && $isSubnet;
```

You can use `FILTER_FLAG_IPV4/6` in first check as third parameter to ensure desired format.